# DSRA0304E: XAException occurred. Could not load the DLL sqljdbc.dll, or one of the DLLs it references

Tags: rhel, ibm-was

I am getting error when hit the application url:

Error Code:

```
DSRA0304E:  XAException occurred. XAException contents and details are: The cause is               : null.

DSRA0302E:  XAException occurred.  Error code is: XAER_RMERR (-3).  Exception is: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Could not load the DLL sqljdbc.dll, or one of the DLLs it references. Reason: 126(The specified module could not be found.)
```

Previously I was able to access application but after restrating services i am not able to access.
I am using IBM WAS  8.5.5.8
Linux RHEL 6.7

Comment: Can you explain what "restrating services" [sic] means?  You restarted the app server?  SQLServer?  Other Unix services?

Comment: AppServer, dmgr and nodeagent

Answer (score 2):

In order to use the XA support in the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver, you need to first go through some installation steps that involve adding a DLL file (sqljdbc.dll) from the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver to the Microsoft SQL Server installation, creating stored procedures (xa_install.sql), and granting access via the SqlJDBCXAUser role.

Here is a link to the instructions from Microsoft,

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa342335%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

and there is also some useful information within the comments inside the  xa_install.sql file.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the sqljdbc.dll file was missing. So I placed that file in bin directory of where SqlServer is installed.